# how to use firebase query in if else condition

Tags: java, android, if-statement, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

here is the code of the onclick of button , what i want to do is on click of his button app must fetch the email from the firebase database if successful it must show up in edit text that email found else show in Edit-text that email not found , here i am able to fetch the email and show that email found on Edit-text but not able to show the email not found (else part of the code ) instead i get this in console

> `W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Consider adding '".indexOn": "email"' at /users/users to your security and Firebase rules for better performance`

```
conbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://(refrence of firebse database)");


            final String searchEmail = emailcon.getText().toString().trim();
            final Query query =   ref.orderByChild("email").equalTo(searchEmail);

            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {

                    for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        final String fetchEmail;
                        Map<?, ?> value = (Map<?, ?>) child.getValue();
                        Log.d("main2activity ","User data : "+ value);
                        fetchEmail = (String) value.get("email");
                        Log.d("main2activity ","User email : "+ fetchEmail);
                        if (searchEmail.equals(fetchEmail))
                        {
                            emailcon.setText("email found hurray "+query.getRef());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            emailcon.setText("still no email found!!");
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: The query returns only the records with a matching email. It is clear that the else clause is never executed. Check instead if the query returned records at all.

Comment: how ,help with some code , i checked if query is not null but found out query is never null

Comment: @Henry: this is a Value listener, it will also fire when there are no matching children.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sure, but there will be no records where `searchEmail.equals(fetchEmail)` gives false.

Comment: Correct. See my answer below for how to use that knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're firing a query, you will get a snapshot that can contain 0 or more children. If it contains any children, those children will have the email address you used in `equalTo()`

You need to handle the `onDataChange()` slightly differently:

```
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                emailcon.setText("email "+searchEmail+" found at URL "+child.getRef());
            }
        }
        else {
            emailcon.setText("still no email found!!");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks Frank van Puffelen your code works like charm ,but in console whether i get email or not that above error still shows up  thanks again helped me a lot

Comment: The warning means that you need to add an index. It literally tells you what to add. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data or search for the error message (this has been asked before).